# Undefined get discord.js node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Hello I got an error with get command/definition cuz it's saying get command code is:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION" ]});
const prefix = '.';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online');
})

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'embed'){
      client.command.get('embed').execute(message, args, Discord)
    }
}),
```

can someone help me with the undefined get command?

Comment: Which line is failing?

Comment: client.command.get('embed').execute(message, args, Discord)
cant define get('embed')
@bdbd

Answer (score 0):

Ok I actually fix it changing command to commands but I got another error: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

As you already mentioned yourself you made a typo in the following line:

```
client.command.get('embed').execute(message, args, Discord)
```

Simply making it

```
client.commands.get('embed').execute(message, args, Discord)
```

should fix the error.

You later mentioned that an error saying 'Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined'

This simply means that the 'embed' command could not be found.

You set it to `command.name` earlier in the code, so check if the 'name' property in your embed command file is indeed set to 'embed'.

Providing additional code from the embed command file would be helpful if you can't fix this yourself.

Comment: Actually wrong i fixed error by changing client.command.get('embed') to client.commands.get('embed')

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add the s